# How to use same JavaScript widget 2 times in same webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I found a widget on Codepen and implement it on my website. But, I want to use it twice in 2 different pages in my website. When I copy the HTML to other page, it is not working. I know i have to make some changes in my code but I'm really not good with JS.

Can you show me how to work the second widget?

```js
var countDate = new Date("Jan 01, 2021 00:00:00").getTime();

function newYear() {
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  gap = countDate - now;

  var second = 1000;
  var minute = second * 60;
  var hour = minute * 60;
  var day = hour * 24;

  var d = Math.floor(gap / day);
  var h = Math.floor((gap % day) / hour);
  var m = Math.floor((gap % hour) / minute);
  var s = Math.floor((gap % minute) / second);

  document.getElementById("day").innerText = d;
  document.getElementById("hour").innerText = h;
  document.getElementById("minute").innerText = m;
  document.getElementById("second").innerText = s;
}

setInterval(function() {
  newYear();
}, 1000);
```

```css
.countdown {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.countdown .separator {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.countdown div {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #45deb0;
  margin: 0 -15px;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.countdown div:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  color: #45deb0;
  font-size: 0.35em;
  line-height: 35px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.countdown div#day:before {
  content: "Dagen";
}

.countdown div#hour:before {
  content: "Uren";
}

.countdown div#minute:before {
  content: "Uren";
}

.countdown div#second:before {
  content: "Seconden";
}
```

```html
<div class="countdown">
  <div id="day">na</div>
  <div class="separator"><span>:</span></div>
  <div id="hour">na</div>
  <div class="separator"><span>:</span></div>
  <div id="minute">na</div>
  <div class="separator"><span>:</span></div>
  <div id="second">na</div>
</div>


<p>How can I make the second countdown widget(the one in bottom) work with same codes?</p>

<div class="countdown">
  <div id="day">na</div>
  <div class="separator"><span>:</span></div>
  <div id="hour">na</div>
  <div class="separator"><span>:</span></div>
  <div id="minute">na</div>
  <div class="separator"><span>:</span></div>
  <div id="second">na</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using duplicate `id`'s and `document.getElementById` returns a single element. Use class instead and loop through them:

```js
var countDate = new Date("Jan 01, 2021 00:00:00").getTime();

function newYear() {
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  gap = countDate - now;

  var second = 1000;
  var minute = second * 60;
  var hour = minute * 60;
  var day = hour * 24;

  var d = Math.floor(gap / day);
  var h = Math.floor((gap % day) / hour);
  var m = Math.floor((gap % hour) / minute);
  var s = Math.floor((gap % minute) / second);

  var dayDivs = document.querySelectorAll(".day");
  var hourDivs = document.querySelectorAll(".hour");
  var minuteDivs = document.querySelectorAll(".minute");
  var secondDivs = document.querySelectorAll(".second");

  for (let i = 0; i < dayDivs.length; i++) {
    dayDivs[i].innerText = d;
    hourDivs[i].innerText = h;
    minuteDivs[i].innerText = m;
    secondDivs[i].innerText = s;
  }
}

setInterval(function() {
  newYear();
}, 1000);
```

```css
.countdown {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.countdown .separator {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.countdown div {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #45deb0;
  margin: 0 -15px;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.countdown div:before {
  content: attr(data-time);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  color: #45deb0;
  font-size: 0.35em;
  line-height: 35px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<div class="countdown">
  <div class="day" data-time="Dagen">na</div>
  <div class="separator"><span>:</span></div>
  <div class="hour" data-time="Uren">na</div>
  <div class="separator"><span>:</span></div>
  <div class="minute" data-time="Uren">na</div>
  <div class="separator"><span>:</span></div>
  <div class="second" data-time="Seconden">na</div>
</div>


<p>How can I make the second countdown widget(the one in bottom) work with same codes?</p>

<div class="countdown">
  <div class="day" data-time="Day">na</div>
  <div class="separator"><span>:</span></div>
  <div class="hour" data-time="Hour">na</div>
  <div class="separator"><span>:</span></div>
  <div class="minute" data-time="Minute">na</div>
  <div class="separator"><span>:</span></div>
  <div class="second" data-time="Second">na</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, the text under the times has disappear in your code, how can i activate them again? And I need to use different text's in different counters, is this possible?

"Dagen"

"Uren";

"Uren";

"Seconden";


texts, and I want to use english words for the second counter?

Comment: It was because of the id selectors. Changed them to class and used `nth-of-type` to target each timer individually

Comment: thank you! these works seperately now but when I put the codes into my website and put the same html code in 2 different pages its the same content, how can i solve this

Comment: How do you mean? Could you add an example to your question?

Comment: I use wordpress for my website. I put the Javascript, I put the Css, and for page "A" I put the html for my first counter. And for page "B" I put the same html and the result is "Dagen" "Uren" "Uren" "Seconden" for both of the pages. I can not display the english result. In your example it works fine but not for me I think because its different pages

Comment: `nth-of-type` would need them to both be on the same page. You'll have to figure out an alternative to using `::before` in that case. Maybe set a data attribute on the HTML tag and retrieve it using [`content: attr(data-time)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr())?

Comment: Yeah but i dont know how to do what you suggest. Can you show me a guide or any example so i can figure out myself?

Comment: Sure, I've added it to my snippet

Comment: Thank you you were very helpful and I learned now

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, to make it actually reusable and customisable it would be better to rename the function to `countdown()` and simply pass in the element for the block of DOM, then use `data-*` attribute on the elements to define the and labels and separator.

Also simplify the CSS, so things fit, you are only centring some text it does not really need flex.

```js
function countdown(elm) {
  var countDate = new Date(elm.getAttribute('data-to') || new Date).getTime();

  var now = new Date().getTime();
  var gap = countDate - now;

  var second = 1000;
  var minute = second * 60;
  var hour = minute * 60;
  var day = hour * 24;

  var result = {
    day: Math.floor(gap / day),
    hour: Math.floor((gap % day) / hour),
    minute: Math.floor((gap % hour) / minute),
    second: Math.floor((gap % minute) / second)
  }
  
  Object.keys(result).forEach((key) => {
    var sector = elm.getElementsByClassName(key)[0]
    sector.innerText = (result[key] || 0) + sector.getAttribute('data-label') || ''
  })
}

document.querySelectorAll('.countdown').forEach((elm) => setInterval(() => countdown(elm), 1000));
```

```css
.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.countdown .separator {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.countdown div {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  color: #45deb0;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-center">
  <div class="countdown" data-to="Jan 01, 2021 00:00:00">
    <div class="day">na</div>
    <div class="separator"><span>:</span></div>
    <div class="hour">na</div>
    <div class="separator"><span>:</span></div>
    <div class="minute">na</div>
    <div class="separator"><span>:</span></div>
    <div class="second">na</div>
  </div>

  <p>How can I make the second countdown widget(the one in bottom) work with same codes?</p>

  <div class="countdown" data-to="Jan 01, 2022 00:00:00">
    <div class="day" data-label="days, "></div>
    <div class="hour" data-label="hours, "></div>
    <div class="minute" data-label="minutes, "></div>
    <div class="second" data-label="seconds"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="countdown" data-to="Jan 01, 2023 00:00:00">
    <div class="day" data-label="d - "></div>
    <div class="hour" data-label="h - "></div>
    <div class="minute" data-label="m - "></div>
    <div class="second" data-label="s"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```